# Is it practical to upgrade your Town Hall before you have everything upgraded to the max?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have heard that it is best to upgrade everything to the max before upgrading your Town Hall. Is this true, or is it impractical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When to upgrade your town hall is a matter of some debate.

The fundamental tradeoffs are these:

- The amount of resources an enemy can raid from you is effected by the relative difference in your town hall levels.
- Your power level in Clash of Clans is influenced by a combination of Town Hall level and the number of and upgrades applied to your other buildings.

You can expect that once you upgrade to a new Town Hall level, you'll grow in strength rather rapidly.  Then there is a fall off in the rate of your growth as you have to wait for more expensive and time consuming upgrades.  Then you upgrade your Town Hall again and repeat the process.

However, during the time when you've first upgraded your Town Hall and before you've caught up with upgrades, you're more vulnerable.  The game considers you ready to defend against more powerful opponents, and they see you as an easy source of resources compared to people who have been at that Town Hall level for longer.

One question you can ask yourself: Are you winning against people raiding your base consistently?  If not, you're probably not upgraded enough for your Town Hall level, and you should probably sink more time and resources into upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend maxing out odd numbered town halls. You max out on 1,3,5,7,and 9. You want to advance quickly but stay powerful. Attacking is based solely on trophies, so you will quickly earn trophies. However you will not get the best players attacking you.

Comment: I would rather say that from TH7 and up, it is important to max out every level. I have been on TH8 for a long time just to max out the troop levels, as it will be extremely hard to farm on TH9 if my troops are not up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you max everything out first then upgrade your town hall. It's really hard to earn good money with a high-level town hall and low-level troops, and you can't keep your money if you don't have strong defense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you aren’t TH jumping, then start upgrading things to mid level at around TH 5. After TH 5, start maxing out resources and defenses. Walls aren’t a big deal until TH 8. Then, you should start upgrading your walls to almost max (If you have enough gold). When you reach TH 10, start maxing EVERYTHING. Usually it will take months to climb THs at this point, but don’t worry, everyone is going through the same thing.