# As a nearly maxed TH8, should I upgrade my walls to level 8 (skulls)?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My defences are almost maxed out, but my walls are still at level 7. I'm frustrated by how much effort I've got to put to loot for my walls and I feel like I'm still not getting anywhere near to skulling (upgrading to level 8) my walls. Should I stay or should I go?

I've been at TH8 for so long, TH9 means stronger base, better troops, but lesser loot. I'm skeptic, educate me.

Comment: Related: [Is it practical to upgrade your Town Hall before you have everything upgraded to the max?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/169579/4797)

Answer (score 4):

Past around TH7/TH8 or so, you're not going to get more loot by leveling your TH up further.  You're actually likely to get *less* - if your TH is a higher level than your enemy's, you'll get less loot from an attack.  Thus, from a loot perspective, **being a weak TH9 is worse than being a strong TH8.**  (This statement is true for any TH vs TH+1 comparison, just using 8/9 in this example)

You've got to upgrade your walls sometime, and if you don't do it now, you'll be opening yourself up to worse attacks later on.  This slows down your loot rate even *further.*  So neglecting your walls is a double whammy.

Basically, upgrading your walls is an extremely painful process, but doing it before your TH is always the smart choice.

Answer (score 0):

With the frequency of air attacks at your level, it's probably not that terrible of an idea to move on. Despite putting you at a slight disadvantage, it could be worth it for you. I would highly recommend not skipping any research and maxing literally every other building.

It would also probably be way more fun for you, which the point of a game, to be FUN.
Grinding out wall upgrades is **NOT** fun.

Comment: The premise that a TH8 base would be frequently attacked by air troops is only true in clan wars. In day-to-day raiding, air troops are *expensive* and are only rarely used as the primary troops to attack a normal base. They are likely to more often be used in a supporting role, at which point the walls of your base are still effective against the primary portion of the attacking army.

Comment: @Ellesedil that's probably true, i only ever do clan wars, and attacks are 99% all dragon, or baloon minion.

Comment: Well, at this point, it will be more important to max out your walls, as from TH9 the typical clan war attacks will shift from less dragon attacks to more ground attacks, which will make it more important to have strong walls. As agent86 stated in his answer, it will also be harder to farm at a higher TH level.

Answer (score 0):

Following @agent86 answer, do know that there will be loot penalties when you're raiding lower TH levels than your current TH level. Meaning, if you're going for TH9, TH8 raids will have a decreased loot, then TH 10 and 11 are the only TH levels left without loot penalties, which are quite tough, and will be harder to raid and loot compared from being a TH8. Check this [out](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids).

Answer (score -1):

finish defenses and troops. Do how many walls you can during this period. Them just go tm th9. Its good to start work on your heroes early on considering that they takd more than100 days to max at th9. Dont sit just to max walls.

Answer (score -1):

I would say upgrade or wall maxed and all buildings like barracks resource buildings,hidden Tesla, and all the research even goleam to level 2

Answer (score -1):

by seeing the opinion of @agent86, it is true that leveling up the th to lvl9, will only make the case worse. The walls are provided to protect the village. Even when i was in th7, i did my best to upgrade the walls and then did i procide to th8. The same case was for th8. Upgrading walls is necessary. For even th8 faces air attack, you cant neglect the walls. Like, in an exam if there are 10 chapters, you cant focus on only on main chapters. You have to look after the minor chapters for may be they become you reason to success. But you can still upgrade to th9, because to upgrade th8 walls, it will take 100 days and all your builders will also be idle. Instead, upgrade your th, so that all your walls will be upgrading as well as some new buildings.