# Should I upgrade to TH10 or max out everything before?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm trying to decide whether it makes more sense to upgrade to TH10 now, or stay on TH9 and finish upgrading everything on this level?

I've maxed out my walls, My queen is upgrading right now to level 25, but all my Elixir and Gold Storages are 24/7 out of space. Should I upgrade to TH10? Or max out everything with dark elixir?

Here's my profile for reference:

[image: overview of troops, heroes, spells and siege]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it practical to upgrade your Town Hall before you have everything upgraded to the max?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169579/is-it-practical-to-upgrade-your-town-hall-before-you-have-everything-upgraded-to)

Answer (score 1):

If literally everything is maxed out except for dark elixir upgrades, I would say go ahead and upgrade to TH10, no point in sitting with wasted resources. – [Kyle Rone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/167612/kyle-rone) in [a comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348485/would-i-rather-upgrade-th9-to-th10-or-max-out-everything-before#comment490273_348485)